# i am getting error while reading the csv file in jupyter

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am getting this error while reading a CSV file in **jupyter** notebook:

```
df = pd.read_csv("D:/echocardiogram.data.csv")

ParserError                              
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8874d53db29b> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv("D:/echocardiogram.data.csv")
```

My system is **windows 10**.

Comment: The error message you posted seems to be incomplete. Is that the entire error?

Answer (score 1):

your dataset name is 'echocardiogram.data.csv' this is why you getting parser error.
just rename the file as 'echocardiogram.csv' then read the data using pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("D:/echocardiogram.csv")
```